# Pull out all feild data on a single model object

Tags: django, object

I'm trying to load user info into a profile page template. How would I get all the feild data for a single user? How could I extract all the data on Users.objects.get(pk=13)?
It just shows that I have the object but I need to expand it to get the name, bio, profile pic ect so I can display it.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as:

```
user = Users.objects.get(pk=13)
user.name
user.bio
```